# Trigger to append multiple datetime fields into text area

Tags: trigger

Hi and thanks in advance.

My goal is through a trigger and based on a picklist value:

1. Append mutliple datetime fields into a text area
2. Clear out data in copied fields

For example

I have a picklist field that when the value is changed to "BOM Changed" I want to take the values from 3 date/time fields: a, b, c and append them into a TExt Area field.  Then I want to clear out a,b,c

I tried doing this through a WFR but I cannot control the order of the field updates and the fields were getting cleared out before the copy.

Again, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please post you code so that the issue can be traced.
What is WFR?
---Update:
Not sure if you can do this using workflow. A combination of lightning process and Flow would work (OR) go for a simple apex trigger/class.

Comment: **W**ork**F**low**R**ule

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response Todd.

I was able to get this done via 2 workflow rules (wfr) instead of one.  I Created a number field with a default value of 0.  When the picklist field meets a certain value and the number field is 0, I run the first WFR to copy/append to a quote history field and then set the number field to 1.  Very important that you check the box for 'Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change-evaluate'.

Then

When the picklist value equals the same value as in the first WFR and the number fields = 1, I run the second WFR, which clears out the field and then changes the number field back to 0.  Very important that you dont check the 'Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change'.  You could get stuck in a loop.

So far all is working well.